# Text larger that rest in php code

Tags: php, html, css

I have some php code to display items from a database. It all works fine and i have styled it to how i need it but within my code the word 'COMMENTS' is displayed larger than the rest.
Ive played around with the code but ir either displays a error message or adds more text to the larger text

```
<div class='entry'>
<span class='link'>
    <?php echo $row['title']; ?><br/> 
    <?php echo $row['message']; ?><br/> 
    <?php echo $row['author']; ?><br/>
    <?php $row['posted'] = date("jS M Y h:i",$row['posted']); echo $row['posted']; ?><br/>
    <?php echo "<a href='msg.php?id=$row[id]'/> Comments $row[replies]</a>" ?><br/>
    <?php echo "Likes: " . $row['votes_up'] . " "; echo "Dislikes: " . $row['votes_down'] . "<br />"; ?> 
</span>
```

It is displayed in row five 'Comments'

Ive tried adding echo etc and i can work it out

style...

```
.entry {
width: 500px;
color: black;
background: white;
padding:8px;
border:1px solid white;
margin:5px auto;
-moz-border-radius:8px;
```

}

```
span.link a {
font-size:150%;
color: #000000;
text-decoration:none;
```

}

[image: picture]

Comment: What's your anchor style? `a { ... }`

Comment: where's the style for "link" class? Do you have styles applied to anchor tags?

Comment: is this what your after...... span.link a { font-size:150%; color: #000000; text-decoration:none; }

Comment: @louismoore18: Bingo, there's your problem. When the anchor style is applied, it's boosting the test size 150%.

Comment: You have a `/` here: `<a href='msg.php?id=$row[id]'/>`. Do you have a `a` style? is `$row[replies]` also larger?

Comment: $row [replies] is not as large... it is the same size as all the other text. Its just comment which is larger (roughly double) that the rest

Comment: @louismoore18: Probably has something to dow ith the "self-closed" anchor you're trying to do. i.e. `<a .../>` vs. `<a ...>` (note the slash.

Comment: @Brad christie tried removing the ' / ' and this did not change anything.. is this what i was spose to do?

Answer (score 2):

As I presumed, the anchor is the benefactor. Your style:

```
span.link a {
  font-size:150%;   /* offending style sheet */
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

either change that, create a new class for the anchor, or be more specific on the CSS selector for this exception.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't style text. The CSS in your page does. Use something like Firebug to examine the comment text and it'll tell you WHERE the font-size override is coming from.